# Can I send a message to a friend using the id, using using Facebook Graph API v2.4?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need your help!

I have friend list received from "/me/taggable_friends" like this:

```
Array
    (
        [id] => AaL-5tuNqmauktZphAAI3V1oMW...
        [name] => Name Surname
        [picture] => Array
            (
                [is_silhouette] => 
                [url] => https://fbcdn-profile...5101399123_n.jpg
            )
    )
```

Can I send a message to a friend using the this TokenID (I can`t)?

I use:

```
FB.ui({
            method: 'send',
            link: {url},
            to: id
        }
```

Is there any other way to send a message to a friend?

Is it possible to get real friend`s profile id?

also: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/945186472191534/

Comment: To get real ids you have to use /me/friends.

Answer (score -1):

You could open the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) in a popup.

```
 $parameters = array(
    'app_id' => $facebook->getAppId(),
    'to' => $facebookUserId,
    'link' => 'http://google.nl/',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://my.app.url/callback'
 );
 $url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?'.http_build_query($parameters);
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.open('.json_encode($url).', ...
```

For detailed options see:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: but I haven`t $facebookUserId... need real profile id